# long Value assigned with Default Constructor in Java

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I need to put a check for object elements to see if they are null or blank or are having their default values. I printed default value of a long element and it turned to be 0. In a review i have been asked to put a check for the long element to be greater than 0 too.

Will default object constructor construct a object with negative value for any of the member element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will default object constructor construct a object with negative value
>   for any of the member element.

No.

The Java class-members have default values as follows:

- `int`, `long`, `short`, `char`, `byte` default to `0`.
- `boolean` defaults to `false`.
- Non-primitive members default to `null`.

**Have in mind** that the [Wrapper implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) will default also with `null`, because their instances are objects, not primitives.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no variable initialize with garbage value in JAVA, you will definately get the default value if you have not initialize the variables in object

```
like for boolean there is default value "false"
     for int default value is 0

and Note all the instance (objects like non-primitive data types) are intialized with default value of null
```

Garbage collector in JAVA done that work for you of default initialization

Answer (score 1):

In Java all values are initialized with `null` or 0 or `false` (whatever is applicable), so a check for this is as simple as `value != null` or `value != 0`.

The more important question is: why do you actually need to check this during construction? Because at this time, the value is equal to what you set it in your code, and no external function could have modified it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

In Java **long** is one of the primitive types.
When used as a class field without explicit initial value, it'll be assigned 0.